# Size of |G:H| in set theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $|G:H|$ be the set of left cosets for $x\in G$ and $xh\in xH$.
It is stated that for all $g\in G$, $g$ is in exactly $1$ coset, as for $g,e \in G, ge=g\in gH$.
But I don't then see how it isn't the case that $|G:H|=|H|$, despite $|G|=|G:H||H|$.
I'm confused on this. Please help, in general.

Comment: I suspect $|G:H|$ denotes the *cardinality* of the set of left cosets (not the set itself).

Comment: Why don't you try and write out a proof that $|G:H|=|H|$. Then you might find your mistake! But without seeing your wrong proof it is is difficult for anyone else to help!

Comment: Example: $H=G$. How many left cosets are there? Other example: $H=\{e\}$

Comment: Suppose children share marbles. Why would the number of marbles each child receives be equal to the number of children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[G:H]$, the *index* of $H$ in $G$, is the number of cosets (left or right, it doesn't matter, there are the same number of each). As you can see, each coset has the same size:

the mapping $f:xH \to yH$ given by $f(xh) = (yx^{-1})(xh)$ is a bijection, with inverse map:

$g:yH \to xH$ given by $g(yh) = (xy^{-1})(yh)$ since:

$(f\circ g)(yh) = f(g(yh)) = (yx^{-1})(g(yh)) = (yx^{-1})(xy^{-1})(yh) = y(x^{-1}x)y^{-1}(yh)$

$= (yy^{-1})(yh) = yh$

and similarly, $(g \circ f)(xh) = xh$.

If $|G|$ is finite, this means $|G| = [G:H]\ast|H|$.

It may be easier to see what is happening, with a real example, so let:

$G = \{e,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b\}$, where $ba = a^2b$ and $a^3 = b^2 = e$.

Consider the subgroup $H = \{e,a,a^2\}$. We have:

$eH = H$

$aH = \{a,a^2,e\} = H$

$a^2H = \{a^2,e,a\} = H$ (the order of elements doesn't matter in a set).

$bH = \{b,a^2b, ab\}$ ($ba = a^2b$, and $ba^2 = (ba)a = (a^2b)a = a^2(ba) = a^2(a^2b) = a^4b = ab$).

$abH = \{ab,b,a^2b\} = bH$

$a^2bH = \{a^2b,ab,b\} = bH$, so we only have two "distinct" cosets (which are disjoint), $H$ and $bH$.

$|G| = 6$, and we have two cosets ($[G:H] = 2$), each with $|H| = 3$ elements.

Comment: Very good example !

Comment: You an angel in mathematician's clothing. Thank you. It's so clear now!

Answer (score 1):

Take this;

$G=\mathbb Z$ and $H= 2\mathbb Z$ then $[G:H]=2$
;
 is it equal to $H$?